# Instantiated NavigationController from storyboard reference the same RootViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I'm instantiating a Navigation Controller from storyboard for which i have already defined the root view controller.

If i instantiate multiple navigationcontroller as follows:

```
        let nav = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CategorizedArticleNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
        let rootVC = nav.viewControllers.first as! CategorizedArticlesViewController
        let nav_1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CategorizedArticleNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
        let rootVC_1 = nav.viewControllers.first as! CategorizedArticlesViewController            
        self.present(rootVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I get an exception after trying to present modally :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present
>   modally an active controller ...'

After debugging, to my surprise, i found that nav != nav_1

but

rootVC == rootVC_1

And with that i get an exception trying to present modally the navigation because it finds out that its root vc is already being presented.

Has any one seen this ? should i file a bug ? or is this somehow in purpose ?

**UPDATE: This was definitely an error on my part, @Samantha hepled clarify that**

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason they're the same is this line:

```
let rootVC_1 = nav.viewControllers.first as! CategorizedArticlesViewController
```

Here, you're assigning `rootVC_1` to the original navigation controller's root view controller (so, the same object as `rootVC`). It should be

```
let rootVC_1 = nav_1.viewControllers.first as! CategorizedArticlesViewController
```

Comment: Oh man good eye, I don’t have my mac on me, I’ll get back to it tomorrow, thanks, I’ll keep you posted :)

Comment: the exception happens at :
self.present(rootVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

of course because the rootVC is already attached to the navigationController, i should present the nav controller instead.

self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil);